# Почему PhpStorm пишет, что set_time_limit ничего не возвращает?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Почему PhpStorm пишет, что `set_time_limit` ничего не возвращает?  Хотя всё работает и естественно в официальной документации написано что функция возвращает `bool`-значения.

Это что, ошибка самого PhpStorm?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверил пишет bool какая версия storm'a,

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что да, это ошибка PhpStorm и вам нужно обратиться с вашим вопроом в техподдержку JetBrains.

Comment: Это смотря какая версия PHP у вас. Если <=4 то всё правильно, тогда эта функция была void. Она стала bool только начиная с 5й версии PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В старых версиях PHP, как верно заметил @DanielProtopopov, действительно был `void`: [ТыкМи](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbrandao/aulas/0203/bdm/docs/php_pt/function.set-time-limit.html).
Обновите версию: `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHP language level`.

Comment: Обновил, проблемы больше нет. Спасибо :)